# "knowledge on" or "knowledge of"? Which one is correct?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I want to mention on my CV that I also know a little bit about Java and C#.
What is a better way to mention that? I think one of the following may be correct:

> 1) Also have some knowledge on Java and C#.
>
> 2) Also have some knowledge of Java and C#.

Which one is correct? How can I mention it on my CV?

Comment: *Knowledge of*, *experience in*

Comment: In its current form, the question is not a good fit for this site. You might wish to support our proposed sister site for [English language learners](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners?referrer=NIy3I1OlXZ2EgMrV1X1RuQ2). Thank you.

Comment: @RedDwighт: [Questions on the following topics are welcomed here: **Word choice and usage**](http://english.stackexchange.com/faq). I believe the above is the case. Btw, it is not unusual for a StackExchange question to belong to more than one site, e.g. unix.*, serverfault and askubuntu. So I think you have been a bit too over-restrictive here.

Answer (score 10):

"Knowledge on" is not a commonly used form, but "knowledge of" is both common and correct.  If you look at [this Google nGram chart comparing the two](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=knowledge%20of,%20knowledge%20on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), you will see that "knowledge on" is virtually never used.  Personally, as a native English speaker, I have never used "knowledge on" but often use "knowledge of."

Answer (score 3):

In the examples, *knowledge of* is proper, and *knowledge on* is not.  However, neither form is good for use in a CV: "some knowledge" is an indeterminate skill level that could range from "have heard of" to "super good programmer in".  It probably is better to be more specific, and indicate items like the following: how many programs you've written in each; how large the programs were; how many weeks or decades you studied the language; whether your knowledge is based on a formal course, self study, contest-site competitions; whether you can knowledgeably read and comment on others' programs in the language.